# Stock Quantity view in mysql inventory database

Tags: mysql

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi12O.png)

Here is my Database design. I plan on calculating the quantity of components in a view by subtracting the `Order_LineQuantity` from the `Component_UsedQuantity.` The problem I am having is surely elementary, but my current view doesn't work because it is summing all the `Order_LineQuantities` from all Components and likewise with the `Component_UsedQuantities` instead of giving the proper difference/quantity for each individual component.

```
Create View Inventory3(ComponentID, quantity) AS
SELECT
DISTINCT(ComponentID) AS ComponentID,
SUM(Order_LineQuantity) - SUM(Component_UsedQuantity) AS quantity
FROM
Component
INNER JOIN
Order_Line ON Order_LineComponentID = ComponentID
INNER JOIN
Component_Used ON Component_UsedComponentID = ComponentID
```

How can I get the proper quantity for each individually different componentID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use `SUM()` function it will sum all the values of the table.
If you want to sum only the related values, you have to first group the values by an `id` and then sum them. That's what the below sub query does.

Here is a model of **Table1- Order_Line**

[image]

Here is a model of **Table2- Component_Used**
[image]

I have filled only necessary details.
You can see that there are multiple values of `Order_LineQuantity` for a given component.

And similarly multiple values exist for `Component_UsedQuantity` for a given component.

I have linked this using the `ComponentID` from Component Table.

[image]

```
SELECT ComponentID AS ComponentID,(ordertable.sumorder-componenttable.sumcomponent) as quantity 
FROM Component,
(SELECT Order_LineComponentID as id,SUM(Order_LineQuantity) as sumorder FROM Order_Line GROUP BY Order_LineComponentID)ordertable,
(SELECT Component_UsedComponentID as id,SUM(Component_UsedQuantity) as sumcomponent FROM Component_Used GROUP BY Component_UsedComponentID)componenttable
WHERE
ComponentID=ordertable.id and ComponentID=componenttable.id
```

Now when you execute the query, it selects the required details after all the grouping operations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I created a view for Order_LineQty sum and Component_UsedQty sum and used these two views to create an inventory view. Same concept and logic applied.